# Enviar un parámetro a un metodo POST en C# Web Forms - aspx

Tags: c#, ajax, webforms, controller, aspx

Estoy intentando enviar un parámetro a un método por POST pero el controlador recibe únicamente el primer parámetro antes de la coma ",".

```
Var Criterio= '00764,98474,84863,95855,'
```

En este caso solo recibe 00764:

```
var Url = '/api/Taller/Proveedor/';
                console.log(Url.length);
                var proveedores = [];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: Url,
                    data: Criterio,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            proveedores[i] = { type: 'column', name: item.NombreCorto, data: [item.CostoPorKilometro, item.CostoPorKilometro] };
                        });
                        grafica(proveedores);
                    },
                    error: errores
                });
```

El controlador es el siguiente:

```
namespace Intranet.Controllers.Taller
{
    [Route("~/api/Taller/")]
    public class ProveedorController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("~/api/Taller/Proveedor")]
        public IEnumerable<BusquedaProveedor> Busqueda([FromBody]string Proveedor)
        {
                return new Proveedor().BuscarProveedor(Proveedor);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Controller]

Answer (score 0):

Estás intentando recibir un **array de `string`** (*`'00764,98474,84863,95855'`*), en un parámetro `[FromBody]` de tipo `string`. Inténtalo con un **`string[]`**.

```
public IEnumerable<BusquedaProveedor> Busqueda([FromBody]string[] Proveedor)
```